# iOS app sometimes crashes when dereferencing weak reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a very simple class:

```
@interface WORef : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,weak) NSObject * object;
@end
```

Instances are stored in an NSArray and from time to time (only on the main thread) this array is iterated and I access the "object" property.

All works fine when testing or debugging, but in the production version of my app on the store I sometimes get crash reports when dereferencing the "object" property (the stack trace actually shows the line number of the property definition).

Here is an example of such a call stack:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x35180518 _os_lock_recursive_abort + 18446744073709552000
1  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x3518050f _os_lock_handoff_lock_slow + 90
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x34adac3f objc_object::sidetable_release_slow((anonymous namespace)::SideTable*, bool) + 22
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x34adad2f objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 118
4  Foundation                     0x27f56f01 -[NSOperationQueue dealloc] + 72
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x34adad5f objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 166
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x34ac14d9 _class_initialize + 536
7  libobjc.A.dylib                0x34ac705f lookUpImpOrForward + 254
8  libobjc.A.dylib                0x34ac6f1b lookUpImpOrNil + 26
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x34abfab3 class_getMethodImplementation + 34
10 libobjc.A.dylib                0x34ada583 weak_read_no_lock + 58
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x34ada871 objc_loadWeakRetained + 92
12 MyApp                          0x000c5983 -[WORef object] (WeakRef.m:12)
```

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: what does _sometimes_ means? how can you replicate this issue? the app crashes usually in certain and well determined circumstances, what are those circumstances in your case?

Comment: You say "the stack trace actually shows the line number of the property definition", yet the line number you show is in the .m file.  Is there anything peculiar about how this object is declared?  (And how do you know that the object itself still exists?)

Comment: holex, that's the thing. I can't reproduce it. It happens from time to time in the production version, it never happened in debug or ad hoc builds.

Comment: it is in the m file because it is a class that is only used privately by another class, so interface and implementation are in that m file.
The object itself still exists as it is stored in an NSArray.

Comment: I'm guessing that the WORef object is a zombie.

Comment: Do you sure, that someone else hold strong link to object and don't drop it before you access WORef object? Because if not, object is released, and WORef in this case will have reference to dead object

Comment: I had the same problem on iPhone4 and 4S maybe you can reproduce your crash on these devices

Comment: the WORef instances are only created and stored in 1 place in the app, in 1 NSArray. And the crash happens when iterating over that array and accessing the property. The only thing I could think of is that maybe somehow another thread messes with that array.

Comment: I see deallocing of NSOperationQueue. Do you use it in the app? Maybe it is somehow related to this array?

Comment: They are completely unrelated. For me it looks like as if the app just does some bogus call that happens to end up on that dealloc call. The call stack is from the main thread and does not come from an NSOperation.

Comment: So just out of curiosity, what is object? Is it the same type always or different ones? If you can recreate the bug, then do something like `NSLog(@"object is a %@", NSStringFromClass([object class]));` What could be happening is that you are assuming your object is a certain type but in reality it is a different one.

Comment: There is only 1 type of object stored

Comment: Like @HotLicks mentioned, it may become a zombie (reference to deallocated memory) - try Profiling with Instruments using Zombies.
Another thing I would suggest is using Crashlytics which would tell you the exact code which is causing the crash which will make your life much easier ))

Comment: I get those crashes from Crashlytics. The copy paste you see comes from Crashlytics ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
// consider this method
-(void)populateArray {
    WORef *ref = [WORef new];
    ref.object = [YourObject new];
    return @[ref];

    // once you get out of this scope, the memory space occupied by [YourObject new]
    // can be re-allocate to something else and your ref.object would still point at
    // that memory space. You would get random crashes depending on when this memory space get re-allocated.
    // The reason being is that ref.object hold a weak reference to [YourObject new]
    // so it reference count doesn't get incremented.
    // Change your property declaration to (nonatomic,strong) instead 
 }
```

Comment: A weak reference gets set to nil if the object its pointing to is destroyed